# Boolean Algebra: Can this be simplified further?

Tags: boolean-algebra

```
AB+CD+A’BD+A’BC+AB’D+AB’C
AB+CD+A’B(D+C)+AB’(D+C)
CD+(AB+A'B(D+C)+AB’(D+C))
CD+(AB+B(D+C)+A(D+C))
CD+AB+(B(D+C)+A(D+C))
CD+AB+(A+B)(D+C)
```

This is what I got, but I'm not sure if it's correct.  It's as good as I can get it algebraically.  Can it be simplified further?

Comment: Karnaugh maps are your best friend for this type of thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_maps

Answer (score 3):

To go along with my comment above, the minimal form is what you arrived at. Using a Karnaugh map, you will get $AB+CD+AC+AD+BC+BD$, which factors to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function is majority (with tie-breaking): the expression is true iff at least two of $A,B,C,D$ are true. This follows from your last term by opening up the parentheses, and can also be checked directly.